# How to detect user if they visited the webpage by press back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, back, popstate

Let say, visitor visited my website example.com and then visited other website (maybe by clicking any link of my webpage or maybe manually typing to address bar) in same tab and then he pressed browser back button and came back to my website example.com

How can i detect that the user visited my site again with back button?.

I am trying

**With Popstate :**

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  if (event.state && event.state.source === 'example.com') {
    console.log('User returned to example.com by clicking the back button');
  }
});
```

**With onpopstate**

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  if (event && event.state) {
    console.log('User returned to example.com by clicking the back button');
  }
};
```

**With pageshow**

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
    console.log('User returned to example.com by clicking the back button');
  }
});
```

Sadly, none of these worked!!

Comment: @padeso How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve desire output using [window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)

```
<script>
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
  console.log('User returned to example.com by clicking the back button');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Although, according to MDN, the `navigation` property is "Deprecated. Not for use in new websites." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation.